# Calling value from dictionary to assign value

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
color_dict = {
    'orange': 20, 
    'purple': 25, 
    'grey': 15
}
```

I want to be able to call from this dictionary, from input() below, and assign cost accordingly to colorCost. I cannot figure out the correct way to call from color_dict based on input().

```
Color = input()
print('Choose a color: ')
colorCost = 
print('Cost of', Color, ': $', colorCost)
```

Comment: You probably want `colorCost = color_dict[Color]` though you have your input and first print statement backwards. This is a question about Python's basics, so you should spend time going through a Python tutorial. Is there something about Python's dictionaries in your tutorial that you do not understand?

Comment: You call by their keys. What you should do:
colorCost = color_dict[Color]

Comment: Check out the tutorial for dictionaries here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try the below snippet

```
colorCost = color_dict[Color]
```